# What minifigure has a textured lab coat?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

With body on legs it will not fully sit down. From a tote of LEGO parts my kids played with in jr high or high school. They graduated in 2008.

Comment: Are you sure that's LEGO?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a piece made by LEGO. It's most likely made by a compatible brand.